# Group application submission status in Australia

Tags: visas, australia, application-status

My agent has submitted a group application for a tourist visa subclass 600 for Australia. How can I check online to see if the submission was successful using my passport details?

Comment: Did your agent give you a Transaction Reference Number (TRN) for the application?

Comment: No he didnt give any trn so far but like to ck online its submitted or not

Comment: And maximum how much time it take to get approved my visa because , done 40 candidate's submittion at a time.

Comment: For Subclass 600 visas, applications are processed as follows: 75% of applications in 16 days; and 90% of applications in 27 days. Source: https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/visitor-600 . There is advice for checking your application status if you have applied online, here: https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/help-support/applying-online-or-on-paper/online#content-index-9 - however this may not include submission via an agent.